# Phone stuck on "Resuming..."

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-930

I have **Windows 10 Mobile** on a **Lumia 930**. Just moments ago I unlocked my phone but it stuck on the classic "*Resuming...*" screen. None of the buttons work. The power button does nothing and I get no haptic feedback from the rest of the buttons. Pressing the Windows button for 20 or more seconds does nothing. The screen is "moving" meaning that I can see loading dots moving, but I can't get to the shortcuts or do anything for that matter.

**How can I reset my phone?**

Comment: Have you tried holding the Power button for ~10 seconds? That should restart it. You might also try a soft reset by pressing Power+VolumeDown.

Comment: Soft resetting with `Power + VolumeDown` did the trick. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to reboot my phone by soft resetting it, holding `Power + VolumeDown`. Nothing else was working.

Comment: hi I just had the same problem, with my Lumia 650 windows 10, looks like soft re-set works (Power + Volume+) thanks!

Comment: I think its Power plus Volume UP , to soft reset Lumia phones.just did that to my Lumia 830 and it worked!